# MongoDB error 11000 but the key has a variable unique: false

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unique

I'm working on a backend application in JavaScript with Node.js, Express and MongoDB (I followed the openClassroom tutorials) and everything works fine except for one collection of my madabase :

```
const frequencySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  // Datas of frequencySchema;
});
   
const reptileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: false },
  imageUrl: { type: String, required: false },
  group: { type: String, required: true },
  foodType: { type: [String], required: true },
  frequency: { type: [frequencySchema], required: true },
});
   
const lastMealSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  // Datas of lastMealSchema;
});
  
const petSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  owner: { type: String, required: true },
  enabled: { type: Boolean, required: true },
  reptile: { type: reptileSchema, required: true, unique: false },
  birthday: { type: Date, required: false },
  shade: { type: [Date], required: false },
  lastMeal: { type: [lastMealSchema], required: false },
  calciumFreq: { type: Number, required: false },
  vitaminFreq: { type: Number, required: false }
});
```

And now when i run my route to add a pet with these params :

```
    { 
        "_id": "0",
        "name": "Godzilla",
        "enabled": true,
        "birthday": "2015-02-15",
        "shade": [],
        "calciumFreq": 0,
        "vitaminFreq": 0,
        "owner": "{{userId}}",
        "lastMeal": [],
        "reptile":  {
            "foodType": [],
            "_id": "5f5695c255b55e001782f8ad",
            "name": "Gecko Leopard",
            "group": "Lezard",
            "frequency": []
        }
    }
```

It works fine, then if i do it a second time, it gives me the MongoDB error 11000 :

```
    "error": {
        "driver": true,
        "name": "MongoError",
        "index": 0,
        "code": 11000,
        "keyPattern": {
            "reptile.name": 1
        },
        "keyValue": {
            "reptile.name": "Gecko Leopard"
        }
    }
```

but i set these values parameter unique to false.

Comment: and sorry for my english..

Comment: If you specify `"_id": "0"` twice it's normal you get a duplicate error ;) Leave the _id field blank and be set automatically.

Comment: I tried but still get the same error, i tried to set "_id" = "" and i tried to deleted the field "_id" but nothing changed :(

Comment: By doing this i get an application error, i just replaced type by ref in PetSchema

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to make a reference (to populate, I guess). It's not `type: reptileSchema`, it's `{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: reptileSchema }`

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: i did it like this :

`const petSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 ...
  reptile: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Reptile' },
  lastMeal: { type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'LastMeal' },
 ...
});

const Reptile = mongoose.model('Reptile', reptileSchema);
const LastMeal = mongoose.model('LastMeal', lastMealSchema);
const Frequency = mongoose.model('Frequency', frequencySchema);`

But still have an application error

Comment: using this line :
  reptile: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: reptileSchema },

i got this error :


MongooseError: Invalid ref at path "reptile". Got Schema {
  obj: [Object],
  paths: [Object],
  aliases: {},
  subpaths: [Object],
  virtuals: {},
  singleNestedPaths: [Object],
  nested: {},
  inherits: {},
  callQueue: [],
  _indexes: [],
  methods: {},
  methodOptions: {},
  statics: {},
  tree: [Object],
  query: {},
  childSchemas: [Array],
  plugins: [],
  '$id': 5,
  s: [Object],
  _userProvidedOptions: {},
  options: [Object]
}